# AWS - DynamoDB Stream - Long polling in iOS Application

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, stream, amazon-dynamodb, long-polling

I have setup a table in DynamoDB and I am able to do query and insert accordingly. Now I want to implement long polling on the same table.

Workflow -

1. Multiple devices are connected to the Table in DynamoDB.
2. Device A inserts an item in Table.
3. Table triggers gets called and a lambda function is evoked which formats the data needed to be sent.
4. Device B gets notified about the change in realtime.

I know this is possible with SNS as the lambda function will sent notification as soon as any activity on table occured.

But I want a better solution when any changes to the table, will be notified to the device through streams or callback instead.

I have searched for DynamoDBStreams and I am understanding upto the lambda part, but I didnt find any document as to how can i get the callback that "an activity occured in table", to the device.

Comment: Hello, could you post this question on AWS Forums so that someone from AWS community respond?

Comment: Yes I can but their response time is very slow, they might come up with some generic answer and point out to some of their vague documentation as in every scenario they do.